# RequestDispatcher did not work when used mockmvc in my test

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a demo filter to log request/response body and verify the request signature, if signature is wrong the filter would be redirect to my error controller. And I have some test case to check this filter:

1. post the correct signature by using `RestTemplate`
2. post the wrong signature by using `RestTemplate`
3. post the correct signature by using `MockMvc`
4. post the wrong signature by using `MockMvc`

when I run that, case 1,2,3 were correct. but the case 4 has some problem.
I found that case 4 has run this code, but it did not redirect to my error controller.

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error/signError");
requestDispatcher.forward(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
```

Whether I used the default `MockMvc` by `@Autowired` or used the MockMvcBuilders to create, this code did not work.
So, I confuse how much different about the `MockMvc` and `RestTemplate`, and is `RequestDispatcher` possible to work by using MockMvc?

The filter code:

```
@Component
public class ApiFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiFilter.class);

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    String requestBody = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    LOG.info("request id [{}] requset body [{}]", requestId, requestBody);
    ApiRequestWrapper requestWrapper = null;
    ApiResponseWrapper responseWrapper = null;
    try {
        requestWrapper = new ApiRequestWrapper(requestId, request, requestBody);
        responseWrapper = new ApiResponseWrapper(requestId, response);
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());
        System.out.println(request.getPathInfo());
        System.out.println(getServletContext());
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(request.getHeader(ApiConstant.HEAD_SIGN), DigestUtils.md5Hex(requestBody + ApiConstant.API_TOKEN))) {
            filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        } else {
            // redirect to error response
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/error/signError");
            requestDispatcher.forward(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
        }

    } finally {
        LOG.info("request id [{}] response body [{}]", requestId, responseWrapper);
    }
}
}
```

and my test case like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class LoginContorllerTest {

@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;

//@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired ApiFilter apiFilter;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    MockFilterConfig filterConfig = new MockFilterConfig(webApplicationContext.getServletContext(), "apiFilter");
    apiFilter.init(filterConfig);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).addFilter(apiFilter, "/api/*").build();
}

@Test
public void mockTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("mockTest");
    LoginParam param = new LoginParam();
    param.setUsername("test");
    param.setPassword("123456");
    String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(param);
    String sign = DigestUtils.md5Hex(requestBody + ApiConstant.API_TOKEN);
    String contentAsString = mockMvc
            .perform(post("/api/login").header(ApiConstant.HEAD_SIGN, sign).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(requestBody))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse()
            .getContentAsString();
    // please forgive me using this way in the demo
    System.out.println(contentAsString);
    System.out.println();
}

@Test
public void mockSignErrorTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("mockSignErrorTest");
    LoginParam param = new LoginParam();
    param.setUsername("test");
    param.setPassword("123456");
    String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(param);
    String contentAsString = mockMvc
            .perform(post("/api/login").header(ApiConstant.HEAD_SIGN, "12254548858").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(requestBody))
            .andReturn()
            .getResponse()
            .getContentAsString();
    System.out.println(contentAsString);
    System.out.println();
}

@Test
public void restTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("restTest");
    LoginParam param = new LoginParam();
    param.setUsername("test");
    param.setPassword("123456");
    String requestBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(param);
    String sign = DigestUtils.md5Hex(requestBody + ApiConstant.API_TOKEN);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(ApiConstant.HEAD_SIGN, sign);

    HttpEntity<LoginParam> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<LoginParam>(param, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> result = this.restTemplate.exchange("/api/login", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println(result.getBody());
    System.out.println();
}

@Test
public void restSignErrorTest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("restSignErrorTest");
    LoginParam param = new LoginParam();
    param.setUsername("test");
    param.setPassword("123456");
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(ApiConstant.HEAD_SIGN, "123456789");

    HttpEntity<LoginParam> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<LoginParam>(param, headers);
    ResponseEntity<String> result = this.restTemplate.exchange("/api/login", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
    System.out.println(result.getBody());
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: You are mocking things that is what `MockMvc` does so no it will not actually call your controller obviously. You should test if the request gets forwarded not expect the actual content.

Comment: I have also expected the request to forward to "/error/signError" but if I did it the andExpect(redirectedUrl("/error/signError")) would get a NullPointerException

Comment: It isn't a redirect it is a forward...

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have read the source of the mockmvc, if I expect  forward or redirect url ,I should return a ModelAndView in my controller.So ,I have to change my test case if I use the mockmvc

Comment: `MockMvc` is for testing controllers, not the regular flow. You could do it with `MockMvc` and check the actual result URL. However if you only want to test your filter just write a simple unit test not an integration test (and use `MockHttpServletRequest` and `MockHttpServletResponse`).